# Amazon Chime SDK Meeting status is MeetingStatus.Left when entering a room

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-hooks, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I'm implementing a meeting app that uses Amazon's Chime SKD React. Here is the
[link](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react/?path=/docs/introduction--page) of the library. I successfully implemented a meeting, and it works well. However, there is a small issue which with which I'm not satisfied.

There are several meeting statuses that Chime provides.

Here is the enum of the meeting status:

```
enum MeetingStatus {
  Loading,
  Succeeded,
  Failed,
  Ended,
  JoinedFromAnotherDevice,
  Left,
  TerminalFailure
}
```

These statuses are managed by the `useMeetingStatus` hook from the SDK itself. I think the statuses are pretty much self explanatory.

You enter a meeting, you get the `MeetingStatus.Succeeded` status. You leave the meeting you get the `MeetingStatus.Left` status.

And here is the problem:

Once you leave a meeting and try to enter a new one, you get for a moment `MeetingStatus.Left` status, and then you get the initial meeting status which should be `MeetingStatus.Loading`.

So my question is, is there a way to reset the meeting status after the user leaves a meeting with the `meetingManager.leave()` method?

I also noticed after leaving a meeting and hard reloading the app (page), this doesn't happen, which for me means, there is some state that should be reset after leaving a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<MeetingProvider>` component which wraps the the meeting app. This meeting provider holds all data in the `useMeetingManager` hook. The solution was to re render the `<MeetingProvider>` which I did by wrapping the router component with it.
Once the user leaves the meeting, the app redirects the user to other page and the `<MeetingProvider>` re renders.

Or, there is also a solution to instantiate a new meetingManager object like this:

```
const meetingManager = new MeetingManager(new ConsoleLogger('LoggerName'));
```

and then you pass the `meetingManager` to the `<MeetingProvider>` like this:

```
 <MeetingProvider meetingManager={meetingManager}>
      <MyApp1 />
 </MeetingProvider>
```

This is described [here](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react/?path=/docs/sdk-providers-meetingmanager--page)